# Syntax error on apache after installing lets encrypt

Tags: apache, encryption, ssl-certificate, bitnami

after installing lets encrypt ssl certificate I got error in my apache server.

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 46 of
>   /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf:  SSLCertificateFile:
>   file '/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt' does not exist or is empty
>   apache config test fails, aborting.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here.

The link to the section about how to generate and configure a Let's Encrypt certificate in our solutions is this one

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/

As the guide mentions, you need to:

1.Generate the certificates with the Lego tool

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo lego --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --path="/etc/lego" run
```

2.Link the certificates with the files that Apache uses

```
sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt.old
sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key.old
sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.csr /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.csr.old
sudo ln -fs /etc/lego/certificates/DOMAIN.key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key
sudo ln -fs /etc/lego/certificates/DOMAIN.crt /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt
sudo chown root:root /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*
sudo chmod 600 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*
```

It's important that you change DOMAIN with the domain you set when running this command. If not, you will point to a non-existing file and Apache will fail.

You can review that it points to the proper file by running this command. This is what you need to review now.

```
ls -la /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*
```

In case it the file that it points to doesn't exist, please run the commands of the step 2 again after ensuring that the certificate files exist

```
sudo ls -la /etc/lego/certificates
```

After that, restart the services again

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

Comment: while i'm doing the step sudo chown root:root /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server* I got error

Comment: Did you check that the certificate files exist in the lego and apache2/conf folders? ```sudo ls -la /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*; sudo ls -la /etc/lego/certificates/```

Comment: Please tell me how to install godaddy SSL certificate in bitnami lampstack. I used this URL (https://in.godaddy.com/help/apache-generate-csr-certificate-signing-request-5269) but no CSR is generated yet also not received the email.

Comment: Please contact Godaddy to know more about how to generate the certificates in its platform. Once you have the files, you will need to substitute the certificate files in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/` folder and in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file.

Comment: thanks, I've installed the certificates. But I cant able to send mail in bitnami. i have configure in php.in and i'm also using domain email. could you please help me